# Riscv-gcc can't recognize opcode b

Tags: riscv

When i use `riscv-gcc` to compile a simple assembly program, it tells me it can't recognize opcode `b 1b`, here is the program:

```
   ...
   sll x28,x28,1;
1: b 1b
```

`b 1b` is the last instruction, a loop.

The program is from `riscv-sodor` project. Why does the compilation fail?

Comment: Which riscv-gcc version are you using (use --version)? The current riscv-tools repository uses 4.9, which may have deprecated the "b" psuedo-op".  You could of course just change that line of code to "1: j 1b".

Comment: thank you , my gcc version is 4.9.2, i change the 'b' to 'j' ,and it works.

Comment: another question, i find in gcc 4.9.2, the ABI alse different from 'The RISC-V Instruction Set Manual version 2.0', for example, the manul says  'a0' represent 'x18' register, but when i use gcc 4.9.2 compile a program and dump ,i find 'a0' represent 'x10' register, do you know when the manual will update ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're using the newer compiler gcc 4.9, which includes a new ABI and some changes to accepted psuedo-ops. The Sodor repository (as of 2015 Apr) contains assembly code that targets the deprecated gcc 4.6-port.

You can quickly change "b" to a "j".

For additional information on the gcc4.9 update:

https://riscv.org/2015/01/announcing-the-risc-v-gcc-4-9-port-and-new-abi/

And the chapter on the new ABI:

https://riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/riscv-calling.pdf

Changes include the removal of v0/v1 (now a0/a1).